# Get Values of Multiple Selected Rows in WPF DataGrid

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to get the values of the first column ("Value") of all selected rows in a WPF DataGrid.

Here's the XAML:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="UPCs"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SumsViewSource}}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  HeadersVisibility="Column"
                  IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Value"
                                    Binding="{Binding Value}"
                                    Header="Item"
                                    Width="3*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Qty"
                                    Binding="{Binding Qty}"
                                    Header="Qty"
                                    Width="1*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

I've already figured out how to get the needed value from the first selected row:

```
Dim SelRow As String = DirectCast(UPCs.Columns.Item(0).GetCellContent(UPCs.SelectedValue), TextBlock).Text
```

I cannot figure out how to adopt this for a multi-row selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a friend, here's what I did:

```
For Each Row As DataRowView In UPCs.SelectedItems
    If Row IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim x As String = Row.Row("Value")
        MessageBox.Show(x)
    End If
Next
```

And added `Imports System.Data` above the class.

It brings up a dialog for each row selected with the value of the first columns ("Value").

Answer (score 0):

Add the following properties to your datagrid;

```
SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectedCellsChanged="UPCs_OnSelectedCellsChanged"
```

Then create an event handler SelectedCellsChanged, from within the event handler pass sender (the datagrid) as an object to the following function;

```
    Public Shared Function GetColumnCollection(sender As Object) As List(Of String)

    Dim dataGrid As DataGrid = DirectCast(sender, DataGrid)

    Dim selectedItems = dataGrid.SelectedItems

    Return (From x As <<SumsViewSource type>> In selectedItems Select x.<<the property in SumsViewSource>>).ToList()

End Function
```

Obviously you'll have to replace <> with the type of your collection and <> to the actual property from SumsViewSource you want (x.Value?). You'll also have to change the function return type to what ever you want is to be (not always a list of strings)

I hope this puts you on the right path at least.

Comment: I'm quite new in .net, mind expanding a bit with what to replace <>?

Comment: What is the type of sumsViewSource? Whatever it's type is, that is what you need to completely replace the stuff in the pointy brackets with, the brackets will have to go too. Replace the second set with the word Value.

Comment: If I understand correctly, is the correct answer "CollectionViewSource"?

Comment: In your example you put the item source as SumsViewSource. I have no idea what it is. When you created it you had to give it a type. What was it? If I knew the exact answer i would tell you. I'm not testing you

Comment: The SumsViewSource is a view in a SQLite database dataset. Is that the answer your looking for?

Comment: In vb.net everything has a type, like a string, and integer or a boolean. These are all simple types but I suspect SumsViewSource is a more complex type. You'll need to find out how to determine it's type, there is too much to explain in these comments

Comment: This is what I have when originally defining **SumsViewSource**: `Dim SumsViewSource As System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource = CType(Me.FindResource("SumsViewSource"), System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)`